# Unable to view uploaded image in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have implemented a picture upload feature in my app. The picture model is polymorphic and it belongs to both a user and a scoreboard. The picture controller is given below.

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :load_pictureable

def create
    @picture = @pictureable.build_picture(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
        flash[:success] = "Uploaded Successfully"
        redirect_to @pictureable
    else
        render 'scoreboards/show'
    end
end

def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:picture)
end

def load_pictureable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
    @pictureable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end

end
```

The picture gets uploaded on the `scoreboard show` page. The relevant code from the view and controller is given below.

```
before_filter :load_pictureable

def show 
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @team = @scoreboard.teams.build
  @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new
  @schedule = @scoreboard.schedules.build
  @picture = @pictureable.build_picture
 end

 def load_pictureable
     resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
     @pictureable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
```

The view code

```
 <div>
     <%= render 'pictures/upload' %>
     <%= image_tag @picture.picture_url if @picture.picture_url.present? %>
   </div>
```

The pictures/upload code renders the partial for the new form on the scoreboard show page. I am using carrierwave and minimagick to upload this photo. The code for that is given below.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :pictureable, polymorphic: true
     mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader 
end

class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

   process resize_to_limit: [200, 171]
end
```

The problem I am having is that I am unable to view the picture. The models, associations, create action and everything else is working perfectly fine.  I checked the log files and it gets created. The problem is viewing the image. The code  `<%= image_tag @picture.picture_url if @picture.picture_url.present? %>` doesn't show the image. It shows a small image tag with the number 4, I am not sure why. I am not sure if it's carrierwave that's causing problems or something else. I have looked at the code a few times now but can't debug the problem.  I am pretty sure its something small. I tried to keep the code concise and to the point. If any additional code is required, please do let me know. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

The log file is showing an error. The code is given below.

The codes from the log files for the create action.

```
Started POST "/scoreboards/13/pictures" for 174.93.38.248 at 2015-12-13 03:29:08 +0000
Processing by PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6GAaLHM6gRRgL6Fi7YdlkHbgIqUG4BXHzBL4cNuu1EOhSpHfcUqPKkwHJ2qLV4sD5ZFNGJaaRMpMCnZE31BL3w==", "picture"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f70773b8e38 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/home/ubuntu/workspace/RackMultipart20151213-14799-hppbvb.jpg>, @original_filename="10464404_515284598620752_6141163632807961194_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[picture]\"; filename=\"10464404_515284598620752_6141163632807961194_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"upload photo", "scoreboard_id"=>"13"}
  [1m[36mScoreboard Load (10.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "scoreboards".* FROM "scoreboards" WHERE "scoreboards"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "scoreboards"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 13]]
  [1m[35mPicture Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."pictureable_id" = ? AND "pictures"."pictureable_type" = ? LIMIT 1  [["pictureable_id", 13], ["pictureable_type", "Scoreboard"]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "pictures" ("picture", "pictureable_id", "pictureable_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["picture", "10464404_515284598620752_6141163632807961194_n.jpg"], ["pictureable_id", 13], ["pictureable_type", "Scoreboard"], ["created_at", "2015-12-13 03:29:08.787873"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-13 03:29:08.787873"]]
  [1m[36m (11.3ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to https://score-app-kpauls.c9.io/scoreboards/13
Completed 302 Found in 262ms (ActiveRecord: 22.7ms)



Started GET "/images/fallback/4.png" for 174.93.38.248 at 2015-12-13 03:19:12 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/fallback/4.png"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
```

I found this in carrierwave which might relate to this problem.

```
"/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "4.png"].compact.join('_')
```

Comment: Can you try this, `<%= image_tag @picture.picture.url if @picture.picture.url.present? %>` and also check by printing the image id, `puts @picture.id`?

Comment: @Sahil I added the code above and it didn't change anything. I wrote the code puts '@picture.id' and the id isn't showing up. This is interesting because the id of the picture should be showing up. I'll include the log files in my question above

Comment: @sahil, I have included the relevant log files. The problem might be with the route error that's showing in the logs.

Comment: Can you also try adding this to PictureUploader model, `def store_dir
    nil'
  end`, where are your images getting stored?

Comment: @sahil I have the following line.  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end. I can change that to  def store_dir nil' end. I am just clarifying what you mean

Comment: @sahil, I tried adding that. It just gave me an error. The method is empty now. Nothing has changed.

Comment: your uploaded image name is **10464404_515284598620752_6141163632807961194_n.jpg** as seen in your logs, but the routing error is happening on /images/fallback/4.png, which is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is your use of instance vars in the controller:

```
def show 
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @team = @scoreboard.teams.build
  @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new
  @schedule = @scoreboard.schedules.build
  @picture = @pictureable.build_picture
end
```

Here you are assigning `@picture` to a new picture which works for the form but not for displaying the picture which belongs to the `@pictureable`.

Since `@picture` is always the new picture CarrierWave will return the fallback path since you cannot route to record that has not been persisted.

So how would you fix this?

```
@picture = @pictureable.picture || @pictureable.build_picture
```

Note that this will change the form method to PATCH if you are using the polymorphic routes helpers like so:

```
<%= form_for(@picture) do |f| %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>
```

This is because `@picture` has been persisted. If you want to modify the form to always POST a new picture you would instead use:

```
<%= form_for(@pictureable.build_picture) do |f| %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I haven't actually used CarrierWave but it might require some additional setup in your routes for the fallback images to work correctly.

Comment: @maxThis explains why I keep getting route error of the failing default path. I'll give this a try.

Comment: @ max It worked, the picture showed up. it gives me an error because i don't have a update action in my controller. Which makes sense. I'll keep at it and see how it goes.